# Need to reorganize pictures in folders named by date

Tags: photos, file-organization

Does someone know of any software/technique to reorganize image files in folders named by date?

Comment: Which operating system are you talking about?

Answer (score 12):

Recently I had a similar need.

Specifically I wanted to move and rename files based on date the picture was *taken*, as follows:

`E:\Pictures\DSC_001.jpg` to `E:\Pictures\2009\2009-04-23\2009-04-23-14h56m28.jpg`
`E:\Pictures\DSC_002.jpg` to `E:\Pictures\2009\2009-04-23\2009-04-23-15h32m14.jpg`
`E:\Pictures\DSC_003.jpg` to `E:\Pictures\2010\2010-02-22\2020-02-22-14h56m28.jpg`

The motives for me for this structure:

- I had 6000 files in the E:\Pictures folder. Even though I had used Namexif to rename all of them into YYYY-MM-DD-HHhMMmSS.jpg format, I would have still had 800+ subfolders under Pictures, had I not used *year* folders.
- Had I used 2009/12/31/2009-12-31-23h59m59s.jpg format, it would have been tedious to surf around folders (on some months I have taken pictures only on few days)
- The 2009-12/2009-12-31-23h59m59s.jpg format would have still produced too many subfolders to E:\Pictures folder and also to 2009-12 and other more popular months (all the many pictures taken on 24th and 31th of Dec would all be listed directly under 2009-12 folder).

YMMV.

After spending an hour trying out various graphical UI based programs, eventually what got the job done exactly how I needed, was ExifTool.

Here are the steps:

1. Download [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).
2. Install it:

   - If you're on Windows, you should:

     - unzip the zip file,
     - rename exiftool(-k).exe to exiftool.exe
     - move exiftool to some folder in your [PATH](https://superuser.com/q/284342/68339) (I use C:\Windows folder) so that it is usable in every folder you're currently in (I use C:\Windows).
   - If you're on Mac, just install the app.
3. Open your terminal:

   - In Windows, press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type *cmd*<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
   - On Mac, press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and type *term*<kbd>↩</kbd>
4. Navigate to the folder where your pictures are. On Mac you would type something like
    `cd /Volumes/MyUSBDrive/Pictures`. In Windows you would type `E:`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`cd Pictures`.
   Use *your own* folder path here, of course.
5. Now launch exiftool and let it do its job:
        `exiftool -d %Y/%Y-%m-%d/%Y-%m-%d-%Hh%Mm%S.%%e "-filename<datetimeoriginal" .` (the dot at the end refers to current directory)

Basically you're telling exiftool to read *date taken* (datetimeoriginal) information from within the picture file and use that information to rename the file, using YYYY/YYYY-mm-dd/YYYY-mm-dd-HHhMMmSS.ext format. Notice that there are slashes in the file format we specify -- this causes the file to be moved into respective folder structure, which is created on the fly.

You can move and/or rename files any way you like with this utility. If your requirements differ from mine, just refer to [this](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html) page which contain nice examples from where I derived the command line I eventually used.

Comment: Note, for M4V videos I needed to use "-filename<creationdate" in the command above.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question searching for a solution to the exact same issue.

I found two programs to accomplish this:

- **[Photo Move 2](http://www.mjbpix.com/automatically-move-photos-to-directories-or-folders-based-on-exif-date/)**

There is a free version and a paid version. The free version only allows for a Year/Month/Day folder structure. The paid version allows for more folder options and some additional file types and handling options.

- **[Photos2Folders](http://www.photos2folders.com/)**

This is a free utility to move or copy photos from one folder structure to another. A few less options than the paid version of Photo Move but it does allow to specify up to 4 levels of folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/wiki/ReNamer:Meta_Tags) with some rules.
[image: Rules to move pictures into subfolders based on date]

Comment: You can also use AdvancedRenamer which has better support for ExifTool https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/exiftool

Answer (score 0):

I know that Zoner Photo Studio should be able to do that, but I've never tried that. It supports a library mode and it can help you organize photos – it can move pictures taken the same day to individual folders.

Is this what you need?
[image]

source: [Zoner: organize your photo collection](http://www.zoner.com/ww-en/tutorials/digital-photo-organizing)

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer > Go to Folder Containing Sub-Folders with pictures in it.
CAVEAT: Assuming your folders are labeled with different dates (and hence time).

Go To > VIEW > DETAILS > RIGHT CLICK ON NAME COLUMN ON THE **RIGHT PANEL** > SCROLL DOWN to "More" > DATE CREATED

Then sort by folder's date created.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DropIt to move your images and videos to specific folders based on the EXIF data. I like DropIt because I can preview what gets moved before I commit to the move.

https://dropitblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/how-to-sort-files-into-folders/